# Difference between random slopes and a random intercept for each combination of a random:fixed effect?

Tags: mixed-model, lme4-nlme, random-effects-model

In a mixed effects model, I'm trying to understand the distinction between the following two models:

`y ~ group + (1+group|subject)`

and

`y ~ group + (1|subject) + (1|subject:group)`

where `group` is a fixed factor containing (say) two levels, `subject` is a random factor containing `n` levels, and each level of `group` appears multiple times within each `subject`. In the first model, there is a random intercept for each `subject` and a random slope for `group` within each `subject`. In the second model, there is a random intercept for each `subject` and there is a random intercept for each combination of `subject` and `group`. Conceptually, these two models appear to be doing the same thing -- but they produce different results using `lmer` in the `lme4` R package.

I'm struggling to understand why using `n` random slopes (where each slope is across the two `group` levels within each `subject`) isn't essentially the same as using `2n` random intercepts (one for each combination of `subject` and `group`).

Can anybody explain why these two models are not equivalent, and under which circumstances it would be appropriate to use each one?

---

#### Sample R code

```
# Load required libraries
library(lme4)
library(lmerTest)

# Generate dummy data
# Group 1:
n1 <- c(15,15,20,70,25,35)
m1 <- c(-1.9,-1.3,-1.4,-1.6,-1.1,-1.7)
s1 <- c(0.6,0.5,0.8,1,0.7,0.9)
# Group 2:
n2 <- c(100,200,250,480,130,270)
m2 <- c(-2,-1.9,-1.7,-2.9,-2.2,-2.2)
s2 <- c(0.8,1.1,1,1,1.2,1.1)
# Set random number seed and populate data frame:
set.seed(123)
dat <- data.frame(y=NULL,subject=NULL,group=NULL)
for(i in 1:6){
  dat <- rbind(dat,
               cbind(y=rnorm(n1[i],m1[i],s1[i]),
                     subject=i,
                     group=1))
  dat <- rbind(dat,
               cbind(y=rnorm(n2[i],m2[i],s2[i]),
                     subject=i,
                     group=2))
}
# Subject and group are factors
dat$subject <- factor(dat$subject)
dat$group <- factor(dat$group)

# Model 1: random slopes
out.slope <- lmer(y ~ group + (1+group|subject), data=dat)
summary(out.slope)
# Linear mixed model fit by REML t-tests use Satterthwaite approximations to degrees
#   of freedom [lmerMod]
# Formula: y ~ group + (1 + group | subject)
#    Data: dat
# 
# REML criterion at convergence: 4638.1
# 
# Scaled residuals: 
#     Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
# -2.9831 -0.6452  0.0085  0.6617  3.4625 
# 
# Random effects:
#  Groups   Name        Variance Std.Dev. Corr
#  subject  (Intercept) 0.02132  0.1460       
#           group2      0.14267  0.3777   0.03
#  Residual             1.02692  1.0134       
# Number of obs: 1610, groups:  subject, 6
# 
# Fixed effects:
#             Estimate Std. Error       df t value Pr(>|t|)    
# (Intercept) -1.55090    0.09988  3.55800 -15.528 0.000214 ***
# group2      -0.57190    0.17632  5.14500  -3.244 0.021938 *  
# ---
# Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
# 
# Correlation of Fixed Effects:
#        (Intr)
# group2 -0.349

# Model 2: random intercept for each combination of subject and group
out.interact <- lmer(y ~ group + (1|subject) + (1|subject:group), data=dat)
summary(out.interact)
# Linear mixed model fit by REML t-tests use Satterthwaite approximations to degrees
#   of freedom [lmerMod]
# Formula: y ~ group + (1 | subject) + (1 | subject:group)
#    Data: dat
# 
# REML criterion at convergence: 4640.1
# 
# Scaled residuals: 
#     Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
# -2.9852 -0.6382  0.0111  0.6650  3.4675 
# 
# Random effects:
#  Groups        Name        Variance Std.Dev.
#  subject:group (Intercept) 0.09235  0.3039  
#  subject       (Intercept) 0.02319  0.1523  
#  Residual                  1.02633  1.0131  
# Number of obs: 1610, groups:  subject:group, 12; subject, 6
# 
# Fixed effects:
#             Estimate Std. Error      df t value Pr(>|t|)    
# (Intercept)  -1.5444     0.1625 14.9030  -9.502 1.03e-07 ***
# group2       -0.5796     0.1971  5.4940  -2.941   0.0288 *  
# ---
# Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
# 
# Correlation of Fixed Effects:
#        (Intr)
# group2 -0.704
```

Comment: The best way is to write two math models, and check the which one is more suitable to the variance-covariance structure of your data. If you go from math model to software model, you are the master of software; if you go directly to software model, you are the slave of the software.